# What does it mean that "actual search of names is done at runtime" in python?

Tags: python

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) states that:

> It is important to realize that scopes are determined textually: the global scope of a function defined in a module is that module’s namespace, no matter from where or by what alias the function is called. On the other hand, the actual search for names is done dynamically, at run time

I understand the first part: scopes are determined textually. But what does it mean that the actual search for names is done dynamically at run time? As opposed to what?

Let's try to compare this to what happens in C for instance, as I understand that this is the opposite of what happens in Python.

In C, consider the following code:

```
int a = 5
printf("The value of a is: %d\n", a);
```

So in C, the *actual search for names is done at compile time* - that means that the compiled machine code for the `printf` function will contain reference to the memory address of `a` whereas in Python

```
a = 5
print(a)
```

The compiled code of the `print(a)` will contain instructions for going looking in the namespace dictionary for what is pointed to by `a` and then access it.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

It means that a name can suddenly start resolving to something else, because it was redefined during the execution of the program. The alternative would be to resolve names when the program is read and parsed, and stick to this interpretation. (Which would be somewhat faster allow considerable additional optimization, e.g. by "knowing" things about the default behavior of Python built-in functions; but it is not how the language was designed.)

Here's an example that suddenly changes behavior:

```
for n in range(3):
    print(max([10, 20, 30]))
    max = min
```

This loop will print what you expect on the first iteration, but from then on the identifier `max` will refer to the *local* variable `max`, and will resolve to the builtin `min()`. Silly, but realistic use cases are a different question...

Comment: So the alternative is not letting the program to change values of variables?

Comment: Not really, at least for local variables. For non-local symbols then things can be more complicated. CPython will actually optimise away the lookup of things it's certain are local variables: https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html?highlight=load_fast#opcode-LOAD_FAST

Comment: @Yoav The _values_ of the variables can change -- this has nothing to do with immutability or functional languages. The alternative is that the meaning of `max` would be looked up at parse time, determined to be the builtin function, and then _that_ function would be called by the loop regardless of what the code defines. You can google "lexical vs. dynamic scope" for some context from other languages...

Answer (score 0):

As opposed to being done statically at compile-time.

For instance in a language like C or Rust, by default symbols are looked up at compile-time, and at runtime the code just goes to whatever was resolved during compilation.

In Python however, every time you call a function the interpreter will look for that *name* in the relevant scope(s), then will use whatever's bound to that name at that point in time. Semantically if not necessarily technically.

So if e.g. you swap the object assigned to that name, then the code will call the remplacement instead of the original. Even if the replacement is not callable at all.